# Short exact sequence with semisimple module in the middle

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Let $M$ be a semisimple $A$-module for some algebra $A$, and $N$ another $A$-module. Let $f:M\twoheadrightarrow  N$ be an epimorphism. I can construct the following short exact sequence:
$$0\rightarrow \ker(f) \hookrightarrow M \twoheadrightarrow N \rightarrow 0$$
Since $M$ is semisimple and $\ker(f)$ is a submodule of $M$, we have that $M=\ker(f)\oplus L$ for some other submodule $L$ of $M$. But apparently, I can take this $L$ to be $N$. Why is this?

**EDIT 1** Similar questions have been asked before on the site, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2122955/758031). However, the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2123929/758031) doesn't convince me (you can check my comment there to see why). Another approach to the problem would also be helpful. I feel that I don't see the full potential of the splitting lemma and to me it's not such a powerful tool, although I am sure that in reality it is. Any comments on this would also be highly appreciated.

**EDIT 2** I also would like to know, if $f$ were not an epimorphism, would we be able to write $f=\ker(f)\oplus \text{im}(f)$?

Comment: Do you mean $M=\ker(f)\oplus\operatorname{im}(f)$?  That is true (up to isomorphism), since you can just restrict the codomain of $f$ to $\operatorname{im}(f)$ to make $f$ surjective.

Answer (score 0):

I claim that the restriction of $f$ to $L$ is an isomorphism $L\to N$, so that $N$ is isomorphic to $L$.  For injectivity, note that $\ker(f)\cap L=0$, so if $a\in L$ and $f(a)=0$ then $a=0$.  For surjectivity, suppose $a\in N$.  Since $f:M\to N$ is surjective, there exists $b\in M$ such that $f(b)=a$.  Since $M=\ker(f)+L$, we can write $b=c+d$ for $c\in\ker(f)$ and $d\in L$.  But then $f(b)=f(c)+f(d)=f(d)$, so $d$ is an element of $L$ such that $f(d)=a$.  Thus the restriction of $f$ to $L$ is surjective.